# Sort hexadecimal code into columns with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, hex

I have a sort hexadecimal code, represent as "id_type" variable. I want to separate it into three columns and the length of the 3rd column depends on the 2nd column's decoded value. Here is an example result I want.

```
0001 0005 0701f83fe4
0002 0005 0000921912
0002 0005 0000921912
0004 0004 00a1d033
0005 0004 00252e28
0010 0002 0117
```

Here is my code

```
id_type = "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"

def hex_to_dex(id_type):
    return int(id_type, 16)

n = 4

for i in id_type:
    i = 0
    id = id_type[i:i + n]
    lendata = id_type[i + n:i + n + n]
    lendatah2d = hex_to_dex(lendata)
    data = id_type[i + n + n:i + n + n + lendatah2d * 2]
    p = len(id + lendata + data)

print(id, lendata, data)
```

But when my code runs, it prints out just 1 row of the result I want.

```
0001 0005 0701f83fe4
```

How can I edit my code?
Please help me.

Comment: indent your  `print` to be in the loop

Comment: One problem is that the loop target variable `i` is being overwritten by the very first line inside the loop.

Comment: Another problem is that looping over the string by single characters is probably not a good way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `print` should be inside the loop, to print each iteration, not the last one

```
for i in id_type:
    i = 0
    ...
    print(id, lendata, data)
```

---

Then

- `i` shoudln't be generated by any loop, as it doesn't increment with a fixed amount (depends on data length)
- increment `i` each time you read data

```
id_type = "000100050701f83fe40002000500009219120003000400014cc80004000400a1d033" \
          "0005000400252e280010000201170012000e484c543530305f563330343730420013" \
          "00143839363630333230323030303237383737363446001400011f0015000e010302" \
          "00030004000501060007000016000202cb3009002499060002323399070001319908"

def hex_to_dex(id_type):
    return int(id_type, 16)

n = 4
i = 0
while i < len(id_type) - 8:
    key = id_type[i:i + n]
    i += n
    lendata = id_type[i:i + n]
    lendatah2d = hex_to_dex(lendata)
    i += n
    data = id_type[i:i + lendatah2d * 2]
    i += lendatah2d * 2

    print(key, lendata, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the headache with an incrementing index, you can emulate reading from a file using the `io.StringIO` class.

```
import io

id_type = ('000100050701f83fe4'
           '000200050000921912'
           '0003000400014cc8'
           '0004000400a1d033')

stream = io.StringIO(id_type)

while True:
    row_id = stream.read(4)

    if not row_id:
        # end of "file" reached
        break

    row_len = stream.read(4)
    row_data = stream.read(2 * int(row_len, 16))

    print(row_id, row_len, row_data)
```